# solana-test-validator deploy fail. Blockhash expired

Tags: solana

I am trying to deploy a simple program on a local solana-test-validator

I start the validator

```
docker run -it --entrypoint solana-test-validator -p 8899:8899 -p 8900:8900 -p 9900:9900 solanalabs/solana:v1.8.11
```

Then I create an account with a wallet with some SOL in it

```
solana config set --url http://localhost:8899
KEYPAIR_ACCOUNT1="/root/.config/solana/id1.json"
solana-keygen new -o $KEYPAIR_ACCOUNT1 --force
PUBKEY_ACCOUNT1=`solana-keygen pubkey $KEYPAIR_ACCOUNT1`
solana-keygen verify $PUBKEY_ACCOUNT1 $KEYPAIR_ACCOUNT1

solana balance $PUBKEY_ACCOUNT1
solana airdrop 10 $PUBKEY_ACCOUNT1
```

I am building this simple program:
`https://gitlab.com/rahasak-labs/solana-localnet/-/tree/master/contract`

I make sure the the local solana is also 1.8.11 (I tried with 1.9.2 as well)

```
cd solanaworkspace/contract_helloworld
# lib for building smartcontract
cargo install rustfilt

# build helloworld
cargo build-bpf --dump
```

to deploy the program I do:
I use the --keypair $KEYPAIR_ACCOUNT1 to deploy `/solanaworkspace/contract_helloworld/target/deploy/helloworld.so` which is going to use the default .json key pair at `$KEYPAIR_PROGRAM1`

```
KEYPAIR_PROGRAM1=/solanaworkspace/contract_helloworld/target/deploy/helloworld-keypair.json
PUBKEY_PROGRAM1=`solana-keygen pubkey $KEYPAIR_PROGRAM1`

# solana account $PUBKEY_PROGRAM1

solana program deploy --keypair $KEYPAIR_ACCOUNT1 /solanaworkspace/contract_helloworld/target/deploy/helloworld.so
```

This is going to try to submit it 5 times until it fails with `Blockhash expired`
While it is trying to deploy I see logs like this one:

```
Waiting for next block, 60 pending...    [block height 693; re-sign in 285 ]
```

It also says up until 60 but then reset to `Waiting for next block`:

```
Sending 36/60 transactions
```

What am I doing wrong?

It's pretty easy to replicate with the docker container I guess.
Thanks a lot.

EDIT: hmmmmm it works when it's not running in a docker container.
I am still wondering with is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program deploys are done through the TPU (transaction processing unit) of the validator, which listens to a different port, `8003`.  If that port isn't accessible, then sending the program deploy transactions will fail.

You can start by adding port `8003` in your startup, and if it's still failing, open up every port listed in the Dockerfile: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/005592998dd107b3d54d9203babe24da681834f5/sdk/docker-solana/Dockerfile#L3